# spider's web in geonodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Good day! I converted the mesh into a curve, to make a kind of web. But how to make them rounded in the center?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: this kind of spider web should be a spiral in reality, isn't it? Does that matter? Additionally, could you share your blend file? What you're starting with to make it is not totally clear to me.

Comment: guys...please....add a blend file to make it as easy as possible for us, who help you for free in our spare time!

Comment: Looks pretty round in the centre to me.. so presumably you mean something else.. could you illustrate what that is, please?